# Render Login Page if user is "Unauthenticated" by redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an app set up that uses redux in order to dispatch authentication information but I'm not sure how to properly render content based on if the user is "loaded"/authenticated or not.

App Component (the entry point for the app is a basic React index.js):

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser())
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className="App">
          {/* If there is a 401 error or the user isn't authenticated render the login page */}
          {/* If the user is authenticated and there is a token in the store render content */}
        </div>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

loadUser function:

```
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // User loading
  dispatch({
    type: USER_LOADING
  })
  axios.get('/users/user', tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
      type: USER_LOADED,
      payload: res.data
    })}
    )
    .catch(err => {
     // console.log(err)
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR
      })
    })
}
```

I want to achieve the logic I've put in the comments of App.

From what I understand about redux, the component will always get rendered first, then on redux's store updates, the component will be updated/re-rendered. How do I achieve this?

I've tried messing around with componentDidUpdate, getDerivedStateFromProps, and other lifecycle methods but I couldn't figure out

Comment: Can you use react-router for your project ?

Comment: Yes, in a pervious version I was using a HashRouter as production is in Tomcat so a plain router causes issues.

Comment: So you can try this https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow tells me if you need more help or up this comment if it's okay for u